# Проверка элемента массива на значение по id

Tags: javascript

Имеется массив

```
var someArr = [
  {name:"name1", prodid:1, prodinfo:true},
  {name:"name2", prodid:2, prodinfo:false},
   {name:"name3", prodid:3, prodinfo:false},
 {name:"name4", prodid:4, prodinfo:true},
];
```

Есть id:3
Как проверить для данного айди значение prodinfo на true/false?

Comment: пройтись по массиву и найти его?

Comment: а я как то и не подумал.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function find(array, value) {

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] == value) return i;
  }

  return i;
}
```

Как-то так. Не проверял работу, так как с телефона. 
Создание функции поиска по массиву , аргумент первый - массив, второй - значение которое ищем

Можно даже ещё проще без метода: просто циклом по массиву : `for(var i = 0; i < arr.length;i++) {if arr[i] == false return arr[i];}`

А если конкретное id, то ещё проще, там в цикле сравнения конкретного id с интересующим значением

Answer (score 1):

```js
var someArr = [{
    name: "name1",
    prodid: 1,
    prodinfo: true
  },
  {
    name: "name2",
    prodid: 2,
    prodinfo: false
  },
  {
    name: "name3",
    prodid: 3,
    prodinfo: false
  },
  {
    name: "name4",
    prodid: 4,
    prodinfo: true
  },
];

someArr.forEach(function(item) {
  if (item.prodid === 3) console.log(item.prodinfo)
});
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.